# Método de Newton-raphson na linguagem em c

Tags: c, algoritmo, matemática

não estou conseguindo encontrar o erro nessa função

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// Função que representa a equação
double funcao(double x) {
    return x * x - 4; // Exemplo: x^2 - 4
}

// Derivada da função
double derivada(double x) {
    return 2 * x; // Exemplo: 2x
}

int main() {
    double x0; // Valor inicial
    double epsilon; // Critério de parada
    int max_iter; // Número máximo de iterações

    printf("Digite o valor inicial: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x0);

    printf("Digite o critério de parada (epsilon): ");
    scanf("%lf", &epsilon);

    printf("Digite o número máximo de iterações: ");
    scanf("%d", &max_iter);

    int iteracao = 0;
    double x = x0;
    double f, df, delta_x;

    while (iteracao < max_iter) {
        f = funcao(x);
        df = derivada(x);

        // Verifica se a derivada é próxima de zero para evitar divisão por zero
        if (fabs(df) < 1e-6) {
            printf("O método não converge (derivada próxima de zero).\n");
            break;
        }

        delta_x = f / df;
        x -= delta_x;

        printf("Iteração %d: x = %.6lf, f(x) = %.6lf\n", iteracao + 1, x, f);

        // Critério de parada
        if (fabs(delta_x) < epsilon) {
            printf("Convergência alcançada após %d iterações.\n", iteracao + 1);
            printf("Solução encontrada: x = %.6lf\n", x);
            break;
        }

        iteracao++;
    }

    if (iteracao == max_iter) {
        printf("O método atingiu o número máximo de iterações sem convergir.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Aqui funcionou:

```
/Users/epx $ ./teste
Digite o valor inicial: 5
Digite o critério de parada (epsilon): 0.001
Digite o número máximo de iterações: 100
Iteração 1: x = 2.900000, f(x) = 21.000000
Iteração 2: x = 2.139655, f(x) = 4.410000
Iteração 3: x = 2.004558, f(x) = 0.578124
Iteração 4: x = 2.000005, f(x) = 0.018251
Iteração 5: x = 2.000000, f(x) = 0.000021
Convergência alcançada após 5 iterações.
Solução encontrada: x = 2.000000
```